# Redirect sub subdomains back to root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently working on an application which was build to work with wildcard subdomains. We have changed this behavior and went back to an normal url structure such as www.domain.com/slug/.

I have redirected all the old subdomain pages to there new page through htaccess and http:// to https://www. Now I just found an indexed url with the an sub sub domain like https://www.sub.domain.com I am wondering how I can write my redirect so all sub subdomains are being redirect back to https://www.

Currenty in .htacces;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|stage). [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do the rule like this. Use the domain name in the rule since you're working the single TLD anyway. Then it should handle the sub sub domains as well.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|stage) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! And what about several? "^(.+)\.(.+)\.(domain.com|domain.dev)" like this?

Comment: yeah you could do something like that for multiple domains.

Comment: You can shorten it. `^(.+)\.(.+)\.domain\.(com|dev)`

Comment: How did it work out? did the answer solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, Made the tld variable in the end rule and it seems to work perfectly. Many thanks!